# Regular Expressions (regex) in vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, vb.net-2010

Regular Expressions in vb.net 2010

I want to Extract number between font tags from a website in my vb.net form

```
<html>
....
When asked enter the code: <font color=blue>24006 </font>
....
</html>
```

The Number is Auto generated

i use:

```
Dim str As String = New WebClient().DownloadString(("http://www.example.com"))
     Dim pattern = "When asked enter the code: <font color=blue>\d{5,}\s</font>"
        Dim r = New Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        Dim m As Match = r.Match(str)
        If m.Success Then
            Label1.Text = "Code" + m.Groups(1).ToString()
            m = m.NextMatch()

        Else
            Debug.Print("Failed")
        End If
```

But got Output:

Code

===========================

Thanks

Sorry for bad english...

Answer (score 0):

something like this should help you. Exception Handling is up to you.

```
Dim matchCollection As MatchCollection = regex.Matches("When asked enter the code: <font color=blue>24006 </font>","<font color=.*?>(.*?)</font>",ReaderOptions.None)
For Each match As Match In matchCollection
    If match.Groups.Count >0 then
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups(1).Value)
end if
Next
```

or with a bit linq

```
Dim matchCollection As MatchCollection = regex.Matches("When asked enter the code: <font color=blue>24006 </font>","<font color=.*?>(.*?)</font>",ReaderOptions.None)
For Each match As Match In From match1 As Match In matchCollection Where match1.Groups.Count >0
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups(1).Value)
Next
```

for more information see [VB.NET Regex.Match](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match-vbnet) and [VB.NET Regex.Matches](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-matches-vbnet)

Answer (score 0):

You should [not use regex to parse HTML](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Options :

1. A parser like [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)
2. The parser exposed in [HTMLDocument.GetElementsByTagName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
3. Any other HTML parser